# A question about linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

My attempt:

for (a): any vector space $R^n$ with n+1 vectors are linearly depandent

```
(b) : i observed that 3 of the vectors form are L.I 
    so maximal subset of S is any vectors 
    but what about any subset of S with 4 vectors is there any way to say 
     maximal vectors of S
```

(c): i don't have a idea

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}^{4,1}$? I'm not familiar with that notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Any $n+1$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are linearly dependent.

(b) Consider the matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
 14 & 2 & 10 & 6 & -6 \\
 16 & -5 & 8 & 6 & 0 \\
 3 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 13 & -4 & 11 & 6 & -9
\end{pmatrix}
If from the first column you subtract $7$ times the second column, you get
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & 10 & 6 & -6 \\
 51 & -5 & 8 & 6 & 0 \\
 -25 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 41 & -4 & 11 & 6 & -9
\end{pmatrix}
Now you continue the same way: from the third column you subtract $5$ times the second one, from the fourth column you subtract $3$ times the second one and to the fifth column you add $3$ times the second one. You will get:
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 51 & -5 & 33 & 21 & -15 \\
 -25 & 4 & -19 & -11 & 13 \\
 41 & -4 & 31 & 18 & -21
\end{pmatrix}
Now, you add twice the third line to the second one. You will get:
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 3 & -5 & -1 & 11 \\
 -25 & 4 & -19 & -11 & 13 \\
 41 & -4 & 31 & 18 & -21
\end{pmatrix}
Now use that $1$ on the left so that the second to the fifth elements of the second line are equal to $0$. You will get:
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -25 & 79 & -144 & -36 & 288 \\
 41 & -127 & 236 & 59 & -472
\end{pmatrix}
Note that the fourth column is $\frac14$ of the third one and that the fifth column is minus twice the third one. So, the space spanned by the columns has dimension $3$ and therefore no maximal linearly independent subset can have more than $3$ elements. Take the first three columns (of the original ones). Since the determinant of the matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
14&2&10\\ 16&-5&8\\ 3&4&1
\end{pmatrix}
is not $0$, the first three columns are linearly independent.

(c) Since this last determinant is not $0$, the only real numbers $x$, $y$, and $z$ such that

$x\begin{pmatrix}14\\16\\3\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}2\\-5\\4\end{pmatrix}+z\begin{pmatrix}10\\8\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$

are $x=y=z=0$. Therefore,

\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}

is not a linear combination of the first three columns. So, simply add

\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}

to the first three columns and you will get a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{4,1}$.